# How do you open a hxs file?

Tags: chm

I understand that a hxs file is a compiled help file, a replacement for .chm files, but I can't seem to open them.

I've read that you read them with the help explorer, dexplore.exe found here:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Help 9\dexplore.exe

When I try opening the file with dexplore, it asks me to save the file to disk, or open with another program.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if you want to look through them programmatically or with some tool, but Help Explorer can open hxs files and extract contents. CHM files (the precursor to hxs) were a custom binary format with indexing and other data at the beginning of the file, and a zip archive in the rest.

You can also decompile hxs using HxComp.exe

EDIT: That link appears to be broken/down or something, but your answer did lead me to find [Help Explorer Viewer](http://download.cnet.com/Help-Explorer-Viewer/3000-6675_4-10666661.html), which may or may not be the same program, but it does the job.

Edit: I've deleted all broken links to spare confusion.

Answer (score 3):

After a bit more research, it looks like these files must be installed into the IDE when you install 3rd party tools.  There is a diagnostic tool called Namespace#.  You can see details about it here:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/NamespaceSharp

Comment: The link is dead, and I cannot find any distributive of it. But the tool existed once. Here is a proof of it. https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34279BF3-8DC8-426F-8F5C-CE4092CEDDFA

Answer (score 2):

HXS file extension - Microsoft Help compiled storage file. It is only one among the: HxI, HxS, HxC, HxT, HxK witch is known as MS HTML Help 2.

[Help Explorer Viewer](http://download.cnet.com/Help-Explorer-Viewer/3000-6675_4-10666661.html) may be used to open this file.